# How do I order my query by a field and still group by a subset of that field in db2?

Tags: db2

Sorry if the title is confusing. Here is the query I have

```
Select MONTH(DATE(TIMESTAMP)), SUM(FIELD1), SUM(FIELD2) from TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2009-07-26 00:00:00' AND '2010-02-24 23:59:59' GROUP BY MONTH(DATE(TIMESTAMP))
```

This will let me get the month number out of the query. The problem is that right now it is sorting the months 1,2,3,4.... when it spans two separate years. I need to be able to sort this query by year then month.

If I add "ORDER BY TIMESTAMP" at the end of my query I get this error:

Column TIMESTAMP or expression in SELECT list not valid. SQLCODE=-122

Also I changed the field names for this question to keep it clear the field isn't actually called TIMESTAMP

Comment: It's odd that you can't order by a timestamp field, I do it all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by year then month.:

```
SELECT YEAR(YourField),
Month(YourField),
SUM(Field1),
SUM(Field2)
FROM Table
WHERE...
GROUP BY
YEAR(YourField),
Month(YourField)
ORDER BY
YEAR(YourField),
Month(YourField)
```